# how to configure QT creator cross compiling

Tags: linux, qt, gcc

> Actually i installed QT creator in my debian linux system which is having i386 processor.Now i need to cross compile the QT for debian linux with ARM processor.
>
> So for this cross compile process i installed the compiler arm-linux-gnueabi-gcc-4.4 manually and add it in the QT creator "Tools->Options->Build&Run-->Compiler".
>
> After that i have no idea of how to configure the installed (arm-linux-gnueabi-gcc-4.4) compiler in kit option. Because in kit option "Device Type" , it is expecting for the Qmake file of arm-linux-gnueabi-gcc-4.4.Here my doubt is
>
> 1. Is it possible to create Qmake file for the compiler (arm-linux-gnueabi-gcc-4.4)
> 2. If that case what is the procedure to create Qmake file for the compiler (arm-linux-gnueabi-gcc-4.4)
> 3. If not in the case any dependencies need to install.
> 4. By googling around for this solution finally i felt my head rotate because in QT document[QT document](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1500635/sivanesan) they mention 5 steps.Among 5 steps i stuck in 2nd step itself (./configure -embedded arm -xplatform qws/linux-arm-g++ ).In this step im not able to understand what is configure , embedded, arm, xplatform etc...
> 5. In some link [link number 2](http://developer.toradex.com/how-to/how-to-set-up-qt-creator-to-cross-compile-for-embedded-linux) they suggested to install bitbake and some steps.Here im not able to install bitbake also.
> 6. In some qt documents they mentioned embedded linux (is embedded linux is a OS like debian) and mkspecs etc..
>
> Finally i decided to create Qmake file for the compiler arm-linux-gnueabi-gcc-4.4 but not having the single clue also.So if anybody knows what exactly i need to configure QT creator (either Qmake for compiler arm-linux-gnueabi-4.4  or something else ) so that i will follow exactly the required thing without any confusion.

Comment: This is not a straight forward job. You have to download the `Qt` source code, cross compile (like you mentioned in step 4) it, setup root file system of the target system (what you call embedded linux), use this to configure the `Qt` arm kit. BuildRoot (http://buildroot.uclibc.org) might be helpful to you. Check it out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Qt cross compiling for arm based board can be sucessfully done using Angstrom cross compiler. Just download Angstrom cross compiler as per your board configuration  , unpack it and create cross compiler using that package.